# How to Shift column position in table structure. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table

> **ID  |  ClientID  | Contact  | Tag  | Email | Designation**

I want `Designation` to be shifted next to `ClientID` column.

> **ID | ClientID | Designation | Contact | Tag | Email**

Is there a SQL query or SQL Server stored procedure that I am not aware of to do this ?
Otherwise I am planning of creating new table with required structure , copying the data ( few records ) and dropping the original table.

Thanks..

Comment: You can "reorder" columns in the designer of the SSMS, but it also will create a new table and drop the old one after copying the data. Do you really need a certain ordering of columns???

Comment: yes , i order of columns is required ,can't it be done without deleting data ??

Comment: As far as i know, SQL Server does not support inserting columns in a certain position, new colmuns are added at the "end" of the exsting columns. If you use the SSMS it will create a tmporary table with the desired column order, copy the data on saving and will drop the old table, the tmporary table will then be renamed to the original name.

Comment: The order of columns in a relational database is **irrelevant** - if you need this output - just write a `SELECT` that selects the columns in the right order ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view. 
A view contains rows and columns, just like a real table. The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database ([w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)):

```
CREATE VIEW myOrderedTable
AS
SELECT ID, ClientID, Designation, Contact, Tag, Email
FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to shift the ordering of the columns. Actually it doesn't matter at all. Tables are just containers of records. All you need to do is to select the columns on your desired order, eg

```
SELECT ID, ClientID, Designation, Contact, Tag, Email
FROM tableName
```

Comment: there is long story behind why I want to this , actually made a mistake and trying to hide it from boss . Want the table structure like mentioned above , plz help

Comment: actually you can't. the best way is to create new table and copy records from it using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

Comment: Just got to love hiding mistakes instead of fixing them... :)